# Atom автокомплит JavaScript в HTML файлах

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, atom

Подскажите, можно ли как-то настроить автокомплит js в файлах HTML? Я уже всякое перепробовал и ничего не получается. Когда создаю файл .js то автокомплит js работает нормально, и в файлах html пока пишешь html автокомплит работает, но заставить работать автокомплит js в html не получается. Это большой минус. Помогите разобраться.

Comment: В VS Code работает.

Comment: Работает, но мне VSCode не очень нравится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет никаких ответов. Пришлось разбираться самому.
Итак, устанавливаем пакет atom ternjs. После этого в нашем проекте проходим в меню Packages / Atom Ternjs / Configure Project. В открывшемся разделе настроек устанавливаем галочку возле jquery и сохраняем настройки.
После этого для успешной работы у нас должна быть открыта вкладка с каким либо файлом с расширением .js. Я просто создаю пустой файл javascript.js и всё. После этого автокомплит успешно работает.

Да, сложновато, но пока нашел только такое решение.